# Ubuntu 19.10 upgrade to 20.04 (Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.)

Tags: upgrade, 20.04

I am trying to upgrade my version 19.10 to 20.04. The "Software Updater"  says:

**The software on this computer is up to date.**

However, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is now available (You have 19.10)

But when I click on the "Upgrade..." button nothing happens. I tried to do it in the commandline and that also Ubuntu does not work:

[Here is a snapshot of what I have done in command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtLAG.png)

Comment: You are not fully-upgraded; your picture shows that (please provide text as I then copy & use your text, but we can't use pictures in the same way).  Either you've not applied the upgrade (`sudo apt full-upgrade`) or you've put a (`apt-mark`) hold on packages that may have prevented the package to fully-upgrade.

Comment: Try to use apt update instead of apt-get update. It'll show you if the packages are up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You are not fully upgraded.  To fix that held-back package, you can try these methods:  First, run the command

```
sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade
```

And it should install the held-back packages.  It is safe, and usually does the trick.  If that doesn't work, see the list of held packages with:

```
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

And then you can unhold that package with:

```
sudo apt-mark unhold <package-name>
```

And then install:

```
sudo apt-get install -y <package>
```

Another way is to use `aptitude`. The command to use would be:

```
sudo aptitude safe-upgrade
```

`safe-upgrade` because it won't remove packages *unless they're unused*.

You can also run the `dist-upgrade`, which will force-install packages and dependencies, but *be careful* with that.  Sometimes it may *remove* packages to resolve dependency problems, which could make things even worse.  So please, try the methods above before resorting to `dist-upgrade`.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks Ollie, Much appreciated. Unfortunately though it did not work. The first command ran ok, but still got the same message when tried to "do-release-upgrade". The I found that libwacom was on hold so I cancelled the hold and installed. I checked that nothing else was on hold but still got the same message. By the way I also got the following from the first command:  $ sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade

The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  liblldb-9
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
The following packages have been kept back:
  lldb

Comment: @Moe, I've added some things to my answer.

Comment: Hi Ollie, the sudo aptitude did the trick. Although I had to install the aptitude. Thank you again. I am now upgraded to 20.04 :)