# Software Upgrader does nothing on attempting to upgrade to 20.04

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, update-manager

I am attempting to upgrade to 20.04 from 19.10. I enter the updater, install all unsatisfied dependencies, missing updates etc. It then offers me the chance to upgrade. I hit return and nothing happens. AT ALL. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, it didn't I eventually found most of what I needed at: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1249849/ubuntu-19-10-upgrade-to-20-04-please-install-all-available-updates-for-your-rel , although I had to tweak it quite a bit

Answer (score 2):

This finally worked for me to locate and fix the broken packages that I had:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Followed by

```
sudo aptitude why-not <package_name>
```

for each package listed, then accepting the solution offered. A bit clunky and manual and it might be less than ideal in many cases but it worked this time and now Synaptic says I have no broken packages any more.

Hope that this helps someone.

Comment: There's a footnote to this! **USE WITH GREAT CARE** I accepted all the solutions offered on another occasion and it ended up breaking my system and I  had to do a complete rebuild! Undoubtedly though, it does have its uses.